# Scala: the magic behind implicits

Tags: scala

I've been playing with "implicits" in Scala all weekend but I'm still having trouble grasping the whole concept. This question is based off of my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227585/scala-read-from-outside-in-instead-of-inside-out). I decided to take things a step further with:

```
def a(b: String)(implicit c: () => String = () => "") = {
    println(s"$b - up next is "+c());c();b
}

implicit def conv(s: => String) = () => s
```

That's when things start to get a little whacky:

```
scala> a("1")(a("2")(a("3")))
3 - up next is 
2 - up next is 3
3 - up next is 
1 - up next is 2
3 - up next is 
2 - up next is 3
3 - up next is
```

The basic idea here is to get each line to reference each other like so:

```
1
2 from 1
3 from 2
4 from 3
```

---

1. Correct me if I'm wrong, but using implicit in this case will insert a string when one is found..? I'm not sure why it's printing out 7 lines instead of 3
2. What am I doing wrong here? I'm starting to think that using implicits gives me less control
3. Not as important, but is there a more safe way to go about implicits? A way that allows me to see exactly what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking `c` twice, instead only invoke it once:

```
def a(b: String)(implicit c: () => String = () => "") = {
  println(s"$b - up next is " + c())
  b
}
```

Which then produces:

```
3 - up next is 
2 - up next is 3
1 - up next is 2
```

Even though `a("1")` gets invoked first, it has to invoke the `() => String` it is passed before producing any output. As a result, `a("3")` is the first one to produce output.

You need to turn this around, and have `a("2")` tell `a("3")` that it is being invoked from `a("2")`:

```
def a(current: String, next: String => Unit = _ => ())(prev: String) = {
  println(s"$current from $prev")
  next(current)
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
a("1", a("2", a("3")))("nothing")
```

Which produces:

```
1 from nothing
2 from 1
3 from 2
```

To answer three of your points:

1. No, your implicit parameter takes a `() => String`, not a `String`.
2. See above, you don't need implicits here.
3. Read up on the `-Xlog-implicits`, `-Xlog-implicit-conversions` and `-Xprint:all` options.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed the way you're invoking it. Do you have an example of invoking it like: `a("1")(a("2")(a("3")))` and having it return `1; 2 from 1; 3 from 2` (like in your second example)?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make that work syntactically.